# Working with react-router, I'm trying to pass a function that returns an element to the <Route /> element option, but I constantly get errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-props

I am building a small `react-router` practice project and I am trying to pass some made up information about a dog to a `<Route exact path="/dogs/:name" element={in here}/>` by passing a function that returns a dynamic `<DogDetail {...props} dog={currentDog}/>` component that has the relevant information passed in as props. However I keep receiving one of two errors every time I try to do so:

1. Matched leaf route at location "/dogs/hazel" does not have an element. This means it will render an `<Outlet />` with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.
2. Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of `<Component />` from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Here is the code I have:

```
class App extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    dogs: [
      {
        name: "Daisy",
        age: 2,
        src: daisy,
        facts: [
          "Daisy is our newest love.",
          "Daisy is a terrible guard dog.",
          "Daisy wants to cuddle with you!",
          "Daisy just wanted a home and now she has that plus love",
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "Hazel",
        age: 6,
        src: hazel,

        facts: [
          "Hazel had soooo much energy!",
          "Hazel wanted love and her big sis, Maci.",
          "Hazel loved us more than anything but she would have still gone home with a stranger any day",
          "Hazel loved eating food slightly more than Maci did",
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "Tubby",
        age: 7,
        src: tubby,
        facts: [
          "Tubby was the smartest dog",
          "Tubby did not like walks or exercise.",
          "Tubby preferred to watch over the situations",
          "Tubby loved eating food.",
        ],
      },
    ],
  };

  render() {
    const getDog = props => {
      let name = props.match.params.name
      let currentDog = this.props.dogs.find(
        dog => dog.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()
      )
      return <DogDetails {...props} dog={currentDog} />
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/dogs" element={<DogList dogs={this.props.dogs} />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/dogs/:name" element={getDog}></Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<h1>Not Found</h1>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Right now the `<DogDetail />` component just renders the `this.props.dog.name` but I see nothing when navigating to any of the dogs name.

I have tried passing it as an inline function, as a function that was bound in a constructor, and as a `<DogDetail />` component with a prop set as the `getDog` function but nothing seems to work. Im pretty new to `react-router` but I just cant seem to find any information on this particular problem. I have just been following along with a code project video but apparently it is out of date. It has been teaching an older version of `react-router` and I have been trying to update it by following along with v6 documentation but this is where I am stuck.

Comment: Try renaming `getDog` to `Dog` so that it is treatad as component

Answer (score 2):

In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` component's `element` prop takes ***only*** a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. Abstract the `getDog` function into an actual React component. The `Route` component also no longer has route props, they don't exist. To access the route params you'll need to use the `useParams` hook.

Example:

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const DogDetailsWrapper = ({ dogs = [] }) => {
  const { name } = useParams();

  const currentDog = dogs.find(
    dog => dog.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()
  );

  return <DogDetails dogs={dogs} dog={currentDog} />;
}
```

```js
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  ...
    
  render() {
    const { dogs } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/dogs" element={<DogList dogs={dogs} />} />
          <Route
            path="/dogs/:name"
            element={<DogDetailsWrapper dogs={dogs} />}
          />
          <Route path="*" element={<h1>Not Found</h1>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );  
  }
}
    
export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! I was just experimenting with useParams and got it to work by putting the fake data into its own file and accessing it via import, then selecting the current dog in the Dogdetails component with find(). However, I will try your method here for better understanding. When you say that the route component no longer has route props, are you referring to {...props} in the getDog function? I think I may be confused on some terminology. Again, thank you!

Comment: @SamGardner No, I meant that there are no longer any [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) like from RRDv5, i.e. there is no `props.match`, `props.history`, and `props.location` passed to the routed component, i.e. where `getDog` was trying to access `props.match.params.name`. They are all now accessed via React hooks, e.g. the `useParams`, `useNavigate`, and `useLocation` (*and others*) hooks.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah, that really puts a hole in the way I was taught it. Thank you again for the clarification. This was very informative

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer by @Drew Reese and making some changes in passing the props (this.props.dogs) worked for me.
...

```
render() {

const GetDog= (props) => {
  const { name } = useParams();

  const currentDog = this.props.dogs.find(
    dog => dog.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()
  );

  return <DogDetails {...props} dog={currentDog} />;
}

return (
    <Routes>
    <Route exact path='/dogs' element={<DogList dogs={this.props.dogs} />} />
    <Route
        path="/dogs/:name"
        element={<GetDog />}
      />
    <Route
    path="*"
    element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} 
/>

  </Routes>
)

}
```